# How to color from yellow to Red periodically

Tags: objective-c, rgb, nscolor

I am looking for some help in how to change the color of a textField from Yellow to Red by calculation?

Ex: If my WarningDays = 5, then when 5 days are left for expiration, I need to display the text in Yellow and keep changing the color closer to red where when 1 day is left, the text would be displayed in Red.

Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to UI programming.

Comment: Do you understand the concept "yellow" in terms of its RGB components? It is 255,255,0. But "red" is obviously 255,0,0. Do you see now how to do it?

Comment: you need to do track of number of days. And then use the code as @Alex mentioned.

Comment: is your data static of dynamic? is it come from server?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
int expirationDays = 5;
float yellowComponent = expirationDays/5 * 255.0;

UIColor *yellowToRedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:yellowComponent/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```